# What is meant by "personal impact and articulation skills" in the context of border entry?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, customs-and-immigration, terminology

Within dozens of highly-rated responses regarding both UK and Schengen entry, I see the phrase "[personal impact and articulation skills](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22personal%20impact%20and%20articulation%20skills%22)."

There is no further explanation of what these mean and, in many circumstances, appear to be important, or vital, to successful outcomes. Can these be defined, quantified, expanded, and exemplified?

For the most part, the queries originate from those who don't require an entry clearance, many from US and Australian citizens, although not exclusively.

Tymoteusz Paul suggested that, in [requesting temporary admission](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89706/uk-temporary-admission-question/89707#89707):

> More than any other factor, the outcome of an event with a British Immigration Officer is influenced by personal impact and articulation skills.

Joel Damien explained to the student whose visa was expiring and wished to leave and [re-enter as a tourist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69247/student-visa-come-as-a-tourist-before-it-expires/69254#69254)

> This is entirely up to the Immigration Officer who lands you (if he does in fact land you). For both cases you will need a convincing reason why you are showing up after your course of study has ended. You can expect to be asked this question during your landing interview and the outcome will depend upon the plausibility of your answer along with your personal impact and articulation skills.

And Gayot Fow's guidance to a non-EU citizen who works in Germany but still has a [valid UK residence permit and ask if he may enter using it:](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83109/non-eu-citizen-with-valid-uk-brp-but-working-in-germany/83115#83115)

> Depending upon your nationality and other soft factors (personal impact and articulation skills) you may be successful with that.

The author of many answers, whom I queried, recommended opening the discussion among all TSE users, toward broader understanding and content when such terminology is used.

**Personal impact**: what is it, how is it accomplished, what are the positive and negative traits?

**Articulation skills**: what does that mean, what are better or worse, what traits are preferable or more successful?

Comment: Excellent question! Looking forward to the answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that these terms mean "social skills, generally", but it would be great to have some sort of source indicating if immigration officials are trained to look for specific things specifically - e.g. "Articulation skills" could mean English fluency specifically, or it might mean the emotional impact of the person's tone of voice. If you are fluent in English but you have an accent that makes you sound like you are from some one-horse redneck rural town in Alabama, does that matter?

Comment: [This document](http://www.statewatch.org/news/2007/jan/uk-ho-immig-decision-making-study.pdf), though a bit old, describe the immigration officer's decision-making process during a landing interview.  The section on "Passenger's presentation of self" from page 15 is particularly relevant to what is meant by personal impact and articulation skills.

Comment: @k2moo4 what a find and old doesn't matter; why don't you add an answer with excepts from it; it would add such insight.

Comment: @RobertColumbia sure; expand that into an answer as, yes, you know the opinions formed when one sounds and acts like a doofus, despite being fluent in English.

Comment: That phrase appears comically often for something I would not say in real life. Is it a standing term in immigration business?

Comment: @jdm With pretty much one exception on google, the phrase is a travel.stackexchange original as far as I know.

Comment: I guess people just copy the style and phrases of highly upvoted answers.

Comment: Prior to this question. It looks as though the phrase was used 31 times on the site. With 29/31 being Gayot Fow https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%22personal%20impact%20and%20articulation%20skills%22 and actually the phrase was added in to the other two answers by Gayot too. So a Gayot original!

Comment: Basically they take your person, impact you against some wall, and then check if you still have the skills to use your articulations.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Personal impact and articulation refer to a person's physical appearance and behaviour when they present themselves to the immigration officer, and the way they answer questions.  As noted by phoog's response, immigration officers have a very short amount of time to determine whether a person complies with the immigration rules, and whether the person is credible with their responses.

[This document](http://www.statewatch.org/news/2007/jan/uk-ho-immig-decision-making-study.pdf), though a bit old, reports on a study on the immigration officers' decision-making process during a landing interview.  A person's presentation at the immigration officer forms a key part in determining whether the person should be further questioned:

> Officers might also take into account how passengers behaved at the desk;   their dress, appearance and general demeanour were also seen as possible "clues" to their plausibility and, therefore, the need for questioning. (page v)

The section on "Passenger's presentation of self" from page 15 provides some examples of behaviours which may trigger further questioning (i.e. poor personal impact and articulation skills):

- behaving in an unusual way (e.g. swapping queues to fall further back)
- agitation and nervousness
- uncertainty, evasiveness or lack of co-operation
- overconfidence (in an attempt to speed up the interview process or try to compensate for nervousness)
- appearing uncomfortable in their clothing, as though this is not their usual attire, for example:

  > men in suits or shirts that are much too big, wearing ties with knots that suggest the passenger has never worn one before; men in suits but not 
  >   wearing socks; and people in ill-fitting shoes
- physical appearance not consistent with their answers

However, there is an overall caveat:

> Sometimes it is more of an overall impression that the [Immigration Officer] responds to, including how comfortable passengers seem, how they speak and communicate, how open they are, as well as how they are dressed.  It  is  this  combination  of  factors  that  leads  an  IO  to accept or question whether  the passenger is genuinely what they claim to be. Officers vary, however, in terms of how much store  they  place  on  the  passengers'  behaviour  and  appearance.  Some  admit to forming a quick  impression, which puts them on the alert. Other officers, however, were much more circumspect, claiming that appearances can be deceptive. People who look "very shabby" can turn out to be well educated  professionals, such  as  university  professors; men in the  building trade may choose to  dress up for travel because they wear jeans the rest of the time; passengers may dress particularly smartly  because  they  are  visiting  relatives. [Chief Immigration Officers] in particular stressed  the  importance  of  not  judging  too  much  by  appearances.  Although  an  officer  may  form  some  impression  of  the  socio-economic circumstances of a passenger, this may not be correct, so officers should concentrate on their questions rather than relying too much on the external impressions.

Comment: That document is wonderful. Thanks for pointing it out. I love this bit: "However, if Americans are vague about  details  of  their  visit,  or  have  not  booked  any  accommodation,  this  does  not  cause  concern because  IOs  have  found  from  experience  that  otherwise  credible Americans  are  not  necessarily  very well informed about countries other than their own."

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. I've seen this document before and had it in mind as I composed my response, but I didn't have time to track it down.

Comment: +1, nothing has changed since that document was published. Nada

Comment: @phoog +1 on yours also, and FGITW congrats

Comment: "While officers recognise that this may simply be a
case of feeling unwell, a reaction to a long or bad flight, shyness, or a cultural response to figures
of authority, such behaviour would still lead IOs to investigate further. " - oh my, how glad I am to have a EU passport. I am total zombie after a ten hour overnight flight.

Comment: *People who look "very shabby" can turn out to be well educated professionals, such as university professors*. See [Prof or Hobo](http://www.jsomody.com/quiz.html).

Comment: @ZachLipton: I almost never have a return ticket or a lodging reservation.  Obtaining lodging and/or transportation is not difficult and I prefer the flexibility.  This raises no eyebrows anywhere except U.K. where I always get LOTS of questions.

Answer (score 50):

*Personal impact* refers to how a traveler presents him- or herself to an immigration officer.  Some people may appear more credible, while others may seem less so.  Some people may appear nervous, others confident.  Some people may appear to be aggressive or demanding, while others may be cooperative.

The traveler's appearance and demeanor have an *impact* on the officers who are judging whether to admit them to the country.  In some respects, this may be unfortunate, because it invokes the specter of discrimination based on things like appearance.  On the other hand, an immigration officer's job is to judge people, mostly in a very short time, to determine whether they meet the criteria for admission.  One way of judging people is on the basis of their personal impact, and a person's credibility is certainly something they can and should question if they have a reason to do so.

*Articulation* denotes a person's ability to express a position.  In this case, articulation skills come into play when a traveler is asked to explain the purpose of his or her visit.  The more coherent the explanation, the more likely it is to meet with success.  Similarly, if an immigration officer misunderstands some evidence presented at the border, such as a bank statement, it will be necessary to articulate the nature of the misunderstanding.

For example, suppose a traveler brings her university diploma with her, and this is discovered during a search of her bags, leading an immigration officer to suspect that she has arrived to look for work.  If she has an alternative explanation for bringing the diploma, she may satisfy the officer.  The success of that explanation will depend in part on her articulation skills.

Comment: +1 great answer; this is exactly the sort of information that helps people understand how and what to do.

Comment: +1, you have given a great answer and it is upvoted more than the 'accepted' answer. It's a shame there is only one answer that can be 'accepted'.