# Visiting Belgium with a Schengen multiple entry visa from France

Tags: schengen

I was issued a multiple entry (tourist) Schengen visa by the French Consulate. I already used it once to travel to Paris, France - I stayed at exactly the same hotel as my visa application and I'm already back from that trip.

I currently see unbelievably low airfares to Brussels and Athens for future dates. I am tempted to book my tickets since I have a valid multiple entry visa anyway. But both of these flights are direct to Brussels and Athens, without any stopovers or layovers in Paris.

Can I use my Schengen visa issued by France to enter Belgium and Greece for a short stay in the future? The purpose of both short trips in the future is tourism only, with all the accommodations prepaid.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes, theoretically.  You first arrived in the country that issued your visa and followed your itinerary (that's a good thing). You returned to your country without overstaying and this helps to establish you as a bona fide visitor (that's a good thing).  You have the opportunity to make a visit wherein your accommodations have been prepaid (that's another good thing).  You have a cogent rationale and a premise that is relentlessly coherent (i.e., economic conditions).

The border official has the *option* (but not the *obligation*) to challenge you to produce onward travel arrangements to France. If this happens you can point out the things mentioned above.  Bring all your evidence and and you will not have a problem.

In particular, the border official has the right to ask for one or more of these  during the landing interview...

- confirmation of the booking of an organised trip or any other
  appropriate  document indicating the envisaged travel plans;
- a document from the establishment providing accommodation or any
  other appropriate document indicating the accommodation envisaged;
- reservation of or return or round ticket In general a paid return
  ticket is not required but can be requested in exceptional
  circumstances.
- proof of financial means in the country of residence
- proof of employment
- proof of integration into the country of residence: family ties;
  professional status.

As always, any interaction with a border official is governed primarily by [personal impact and articulation skills](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/what-is-meant-by-personal-impact-and-articulation-skills-in-the-context-of-bor).

Comment: _“challenge you to produce onward travel arrangements to France”_ — what is this part based on? Afaik if visa is valid for the whole Schengen area, there is none “for the purposes of travel to that one country” implied at all. From many answers on this site and personal travel experience for subsequent trips the original country doesn’t come up much. I had only been asked once about applying to a different country on subsequent trip and “went there for a conference as well” was sufficient answer.

Comment: @Rarst Legal basis: Visa Code, Article 34 and Annex VI

Comment: I've tried to look up that document/form and it has quite general phrases on cancellation of visa if "conditions are no longer being met" and such. I don’t see anything that reads like particular focus on using visa for original country of issue. Could you please clarify? I am quite curious about that part since I have 5 year Schengen visa, which I am fully using for travel to various Schengen countries.

Comment: @Rarst if you cannot find the info, would you please ask your own question? Your situation may be radically different than the OP's, and it's likely that if you have a 5 year Schengen you have already established yourself as a bona fide visitor. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t think it’s that critical to me, since as above answers+personal experience establish that it's at the very least unlikely in practice. Thank you for your time on the answer! I'll stop bothering on that detail. :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is the purpose of the Schengen visa: it allows free travel in the Schengen countries as much as you want, within the dates indicated in the visa. And if the visa is valid for long-term like 3-6-12 months, then 90 days within 180 days (total of schengen stay) each time, i.e. max. 180 days in a year.

Comment: Not right. The Schengen visa is for traveling within the Schengen zone as indicated in the application. People who have proven trusted might be allowed more freedom, it is not the purpose of the visa.