# My Tier 5 youth mobility expired 2 months ago — can I re-enter the UK as a tourist?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visas-on-arrival

I was on a Tier 5 youth mobility visa which expired 25th June 2017 (nearly two months ago). I am currently back in Canada for the summer, but would like to come back to England as a tourist, I have a friends weddings and I need to sort out all the stuff I left behind.

Is there an amount of time that I have to wait before I can re enter as a tourist?

Would there be any issues at border control?

Is there a number I can contact for UK immigration (A friend can phone from England) in which I can actually talk to a human being about re-entering as a tourist.

I don't want to be refused entry at border control, so if anyone has any information, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at your other question you say that you have Irish citizenship. If so then why don't you get an Irish passport and avoid the need for any EU visas?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there an amount of time that I have to wait before I can re enter
>   as a tourist?

No, T5's do not have a cooling-off period between the expiry of a T5 and subsequent entry as a visitor.  They are not permitted to switch to visitor in-country and this was explained to you when your T5 was issued, but as long as you leave on time you can return and have a landing interview any time you want, even on the same day.

> Would there be any issues at boarder control?

Yes, there could be issues. They get worried when a T5 (or T4) shows up as a visitor shortly after their PBS visa expires because it looks like they are trying to build up a life in the UK or pursue a romantic liaison or undertake work or in some other way do something that could possibly lead to an immigration offence. There are lots of people who try this on the premise of 'tying up loose ends' and then go on to become offenders and the Border Force gets upset about it when it happens.

> I need to sort out all the stuff I left behind.

Immigration Officers can interpret things in an awkward way.  That's telling them that you did not adequately prepare for your departure at the end of your T5, and for the Immigration Officer it is an indication that you will not prepare for your departure as a visitor and hence become an offender. It's not really a great premise is it? The attend-a-wedding premise gets used a lot also and they will wonder how you plan to support yourself and why you have not stabilised your personal circumstances in Canada. I would suggest rethinking your premises, but that's an opinion.

> Is there a number I can contact for UK immigration (A friend can phone
>   from England) in which I can actually talk to a human being about
>   re-entering as a tourist.

UKVI operates a helpline and the contact details are [here](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) (note that as of August 2017 using this helpline will attract a fee).  HOWEVER be careful to note that this helpline deals with visa applications only, and hence they cannot help with enquiries to the [Border Force](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/border-force) (it's a separate department). The Border Force deals with leave-to-enter and removals from port, so the answer here is 'no'.

Additionally, the Border Force operates a site at '[Entering the UK](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control)', which explains what happens in broad, generic terms and does not address specific situations like yours.

Overall, you will never get conjectural information from the Border Force. They sponsor a user group for solicitors and even then it's difficult to nail them down on something hard and explicit like Paragraph 18 much less applying for leave-to-enter shortly after the expiry of a T5 (or T4).  Engaging the public is not part of their ethos and they will avoid it whenever possible (not to be confused with UKVI which operates helplines and seminars and working groups and public consultations etc).

> so if anyone has any information, it would be greatly appreciated.

See [What is meant by "personal impact and articulation skills" in the context of border entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/what-is-meant-by-personal-impact-and-articulation-skills-in-the-context-of-bor) for some helpful info.