# Re-entering the UK after tier 5 visa expires

Tags: uk, canada, visa-free-entry, customs-and-immigration

I am a Canadian citizen and had a YMS visa that expired on May 10th 2018. I left the UK on September 1st 2017. I plan on going to the UK to visit some friends at the end of November/beginning of December, will I have problems at the border?

Comment: Nobody can tell if you will have problems or not because you may have other issues.. However if you are specifically referring to problems related to the fact that you returned from the UK **only** one year ago and going back, you should not have any problems based on that. One year is a long time to be away.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100662/my-tier-5-youth-mobility-expired-2-months-ago-can-i-re-enter-the-uk-as-a-touri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Tier 5 youth mobility expired 2 months ago — can I re-enter the UK as a tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100662/my-tier-5-youth-mobility-expired-2-months-ago-can-i-re-enter-the-uk-as-a-touri)

Comment: I disagree this question is off-topic as people who VTC has suggested (or the way SE has automatically summarised in the yellow "put on hold box" below the question), as it ask about _short term visit_ **after** a longer term visa expires. It is at best what @k2moo4 suggested - a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing nothing more in the UK than a short visit with friends, and unless you have some issue with UK immigration you have not told us about, you will have no problems at all.

Canadians do not need a visa to visit the UK for short visits. Revisiting one year after you have left on another visa is certainly not too short a time.