# Immediatly reapply for UK Standard Visitor Visa after expiry of previous Visa to complete project

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, work

I was wondering if it was possible to reapply and get granted a new UK visa immediately after the previous one expired? I've already read a few answers that touch upon this topic and there seemingly is no rule explicitly forbidding this, but I am unsure if this applies to the current circumstances of my colleagues.

The situation is that we have a team or workers completing a project in the UK (for a UK company), which is planned to take 10 months. We've already received 6-month Standard Visitor Visas for our team members and wanted to reapply for new Standard Visitor Visas for them when the previous visas expire so they can complete the project, since they're already well versed in all aspects of the job.

Comment: _The situation is that we have a team or workers completing a project in the UK (for a UK company), which is planned to take 10 months_? The first question is, is what you’re doing even allowed? On a visitor visa? Your workers are going to have their visas either denied or cancelled at the airport if the authorities find out.

Comment: UKVI already approved the previous visas, since we clearly stated we were doing contract work in the UK for a UK company, having submitted invitation letters, contracts between the companies, and proof they were being wholly financed by us during their stay in the UK (and not being paid by a UK company). What they are doing is allowed since it's installation of our own products, which is explicitly allowed far as I recall.

Comment: This site is about travel. I think we cannot really answer you for such cases. It is much more complex and it is not just visa. You may already reach the point where need to pay workers (+ all perks are vacations, and social security) like UK workers. [to combat unfair competition]. I think you need to talk to a lawyer or a consultant for foreign works.

Comment: Appending V Visitor Rules, under "Permitted activities for all visitors" says: "An employee of a foreign manufacturer or supplier may install, dismantle, repair, service or advise on equipment, computer software or hardware where it has a contract of purchase or supply or lease with a UK company or organisation."

Comment: Was UKVI aware that the work was planned to take 10 months?

Comment: In the contract, yes, in the invitation letters the UK firm asked to let them stay in the UK for a period of six months, this being the first time any of the workers were applying for a UK visa, so nobody thought they were likely to get a Visitor Visa for a period longer than 6 months.

Comment: You're talking about (I'm presuming) decent sums of money here, work contracts, the whole shebang. I really don't think you should be coming to the internet to a free Q&A site for answers. This seems like the situation where you talk to people paid to understand and inform on these matters, and if your company is doing plenty of work like this, you should already know one of these people. If not, now's a good a time as any to find one :)

Comment: You're right in that regard, but we already did try contracting one of those companies that "specialize" in the process of getting UK visas and he made the whole things into an incredibly overblown, byzantine process requesting we send technical documents, shipment manifests and a whole other mountain of documents that it turned out we really didn't need to supply to UKVI. Granted, we likely hired an overenthusiastic guy, but it still wasn't the best experience for us and cost us a lot of wasted time.

Comment: Your question has been answered. Is it possible? Yes. Is it probable? That’s a different question. 10 months on a visitor visa is a lot of time and this looks like project creep. From 6 months to 10 months. They won’t be too happy about that.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Especially if they find out that it was expected to be 10 months in the first place, but the applicants dishonestly stated that it was only expected to be 6 months!

Comment: @user86252 “Nobody thought they were likely to get a visitor visa for a period longer than 6 months”. The Immigration Rules state that the maximum anyone can stay in the UK with a Visitor visa is 6 months. If UKVI think that incorrect information was provided first time around in order to increase the chances of getting a visa, they will refuse any subsequent applications and possibly/probably ban the applicants for deception or misrepresentation.

Comment: We didn't provide any incorrect information, at least not as far as I'm aware. The project is for 10 months, which they could see in the contract, and the UK firm did request their stay in the UK for a period of 6 months to work on the project, which they did. The only question is if these same workers can successfully apply for a new Visitor Visa to complete the final 4 months of the project or if we need to send a different team.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if it was possible to reapply and get granted a new UK
>   visa immediately after the previous one expired?

The answer is expressly yes it is **possible**. It does not mean it will be **approved**. There is nothing like a cool off period one has to wait for between UK visas or UK visits. Remember we have even 10 year visas.

You indicated the work you’re doing (installation of products) is covered by the rules for visitor visas and was explained in the previous visa application so that is not the question I am answering, ie the legality of what you’re doing on a visitor visa.

Your legal stay is controlled by the length of your visa **and** the duration the immigration officer gives you at entry. The standard is either six months or the duration of validity remaining on your visa, whichever is shorter. You can turn around immediately after the first six months, exit the UK and renter the next day.

We have a canonical answer about [personal impact and articulation skills](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/what-is-meant-by-personal-impact-and-articulation-skills-in-the-context-of-bor) which will be instructive in this scenario. In situations like this your ability to convince the immigration officer at the airport **after** convincing the ECO to issue the visa is absolutely crucial.

REFERENCE

I applied and received a 5 year visa less than a week after my previous 5 year visa expired.